# detect clicked line in an axes in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, click

I've an axes with multiple plot . I would like to know if there is a way to detect which plot I've cliked using datacursor mode. I've already a callback that give the value I've cliked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documented in matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html), `datacursormode` can output the handle of the target line (or any graphical object) your cursor is on. The property `Target` in the following code is used to make the plot thicker.

```
dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);         %enable data cursor mode
cursor_info = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);  %get the properties
set(cursor_info.Target,'LineWidth',2)  %the target handle is Target
```

Comment: I would like to add the code in my Datacursor CallBack ,how can I do ? (how do you write code in this editor ?)

Comment: In your `UpdateFcn`, you can get the line handle with `hLine = get(event_obj,'Target');` and then `set` some properties like `set(hLine,'Color','k')`.

Comment: Ok it works !!! Now, more difficult I would like to know if there is a way to 'mark' the line when I plot it and to compare all the 'mark' with the handle I have inthe callback